# FreeBSD Server .htaccess issues

Tags: mod-rewrite, .htaccess, freebsd

Server Details:

FreeBSD
PHP Version 4.3.11
Apache

Appache Modules:

mod_throttle, mod_php4, mod_speedycgi, mod_ssl, mod_setenvif, mod_so, mod_unique_id, mod_headers, mod_expires, mod_auth_db, mod_auth_anon, mod_auth, mod_access, mod_rewrite, mod_alias, mod_actions, mod_cgi, mod_dir, mod_autoindex, mod_include, mod_info, mod_status, mod_negotiation, mod_mime, mod_mime_magic, mod_log_config, mod_define, mod_env, mod_vhost_alias, mod_mmap_static, http_core

The issue I am having is when ever I write any kind of code in the .htaccess file, it throws a 500 Internal error

I am simply trying to rewrite url's and am using the exact code that wordpress creates for me and even tried custom code used before on previous servers and it still does not work.

WordPress created code:

```
# BEGIN WordPress
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /lobster-tail-blog/
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /lobster-tail-blog/index.php [L]
</IfModule>

# END WordPress
```

And even a simple thing like this throws the error:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    RewriteEngine On
</IfModule>
```

Anyone know of any fixes or why this is causing this error? I have the mod_rewrite module loaded

Comment: Look in your httpd.conf, it should have an entry telling you where to find your errorlog file.  It will tell you what's apache is unhappy about.  Post the error you get when you add your rewrite code.

Answer (score 1):

Off the top of my head, `.htaccess` doesn't need the  bits. Your `.htaccess` should be OK with just

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /lobster-tail-blog/
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /lobster-tail-blog/index.php [L]
```

In it. Failing that, what gets written to your `httpd-error.log`?

Comment: According to apache docs, <IfModule is acceptable at all contexts .

Comment: My bad, ignore that then

Would still like to see httpd-error.log though

Answer (score 0):

Check AllowOverride directive, it can be configured per directory context, like

  AllowOverride All

It should be set to AllowOverride FileInfo to allow mod_rewrite
(reference: http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/mod/core.html#allowoverride)

Comment: When using AllowOverride it still gives me this error. Anything I write in this file gives me an error.

Internal Server Error

The server encountered an internal error or misconfiguration and was unable to complete your request.

Comment: I would second the idea of looking for the ``AllowOverride`` setting for the directory that contains the .htaccess file... I would also check the servers error log for any clue as to why it's giving the 500 error as it should state something to narrow your search down.

Answer (score 0):

Try specifying:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite>
    # your settings
</IfModule>
```

Thus without the .c bit

Answer (score 0):

Hmmm...  Are you certain it's a 500 and not a 403?  if the perms are wrong on the .htaccess file, Apache will reject all requests with a 403.